Sending data to NewRelic
Hello i have a app in NESTJS and im trying to send my data using OTP to NewRelic.
To reach it i made this code:
//tracing.ts
import { SimpleSpanProcessor } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base';
import { NodeSDK } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-node';
import * as process from 'process';
import { HttpInstrumentation } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-http';
import { ExpressInstrumentation } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-express';
import { OTLPTraceExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-trace-otlp-proto';
import { Resource } from '@opentelemetry/resources';
import { SemanticResourceAttributes } from '@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions';
import { OTLPMetricExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-metrics-otlp-proto';
import { PeriodicExportingMetricReader } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics';

const traceExporter = new OTLPTraceExporter({
  url: 'https://otlp.nr-data.net/v1/traces', // OTLP endpoint
  headers: {
    'api-key': 'z', // Replace with your license key
  },
});

export const otelSDK = new NodeSDK({
  resource: new Resource({
    [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: `nestjs-otel`, // update this to a more relevant name for you!
  }),
  traceExporter: traceExporter,
  metricReader: new PeriodicExportingMetricReader({
    exporter: new OTLPMetricExporter({
      url: 'https://otlp.nr-data.net/v1/metrics', // url is optional and can be omitted - default is http://localhost:4318/v1/metrics
      headers: {
        'api-key': 'zzz', // Replace with your license key
      },
       // an optional object containing custom headers to be sent with each request
    }),
  }),
  spanProcessor: new SimpleSpanProcessor(traceExporter),
  instrumentations: [new HttpInstrumentation(), new ExpressInstrumentation()],
});

// gracefully shut down the SDK on process exit
process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  otelSDK
    .shutdown()
    .then(
      () => console.log('SDK shut down successfully'),
      (err) => console.log('Error shutting down SDK', err),
    )
    .finally(() => process.exit(0));
});
//Main TS
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      transformOptions: {
        enableImplicitConversion: true,
      },
    }),
  );
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.useGlobalFilters(new AllExceptionsFilter());
  await otelSDK.start();
  await app.listen(3000);
}

I the data gets into new relic,
Anyone know how to slove the issue?
